# How to prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log x_n$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Consider the sequence $\{x_n \}$ defined by $$x_n = e \left (\frac {n} {n+1} \right )^{n + \frac  1 2},\ n \geq 1.$$
>
> Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log x_n$ is convergent.

**My attempt**: I find that \begin{align*} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log x_n & = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( 1 - \left (n + \frac 1 2 \right ) \log \left (1 + \frac 1 n \right ) \right ) \\ & = - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty} (-1)^m \left ( \frac {1} {m+1} - \frac {1} {2m} \right ) \frac {1} {n^m} \\ & =  -\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{m=2}^{\infty} (-1)^m \frac {m-1} {2m(m+1)} \frac {1} {n^m} \end{align*}

From here how do I proceed further? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Show that the summands of your first expression divided by $n^{-2}$ have finite limit as $n\to\infty$. Then use the convergence of the sum of $n^{-2}$.

Comment: The integral test works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Taylor series to second and third order:
$$1-\left(n+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1-\left(n+\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}-\dots\right)$$
$$\le1-\left(n+\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}\right)=\frac1{4n^2}$$
$$1-\left(n+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\ge1-\left(n+\frac12\right)\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{3n^3}\right)=-\frac{n+2}{12n^3}$$
Thus $|\log x_n|\le\frac1{4n^2}$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n^2}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log x_n$ converges.

Answer (score 8):

Notice, that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i=
\log \prod_{i=1}^n x_i =
\log \left( e\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} e\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{5}{2}} \dots e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{2n+1}{2}} \right)=
\log \left( e^n \frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\right)$$

Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log \left( e^n \frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\right) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \log \left( e^{n + 1} \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n + 1} \sqrt{n+1}} \frac{1}{e}\right) = 
\log \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{e}$$

Note, that this is the **exact value** of the sum, not only the proof of convergence.

Comment: This solution is nice as it actually yields the sum.

Comment: @vujazzman yes, I wanted to boast a bit, but forgot;> Thank you, sir!